# Mapping string elements in a python list

Tags: python, string, python-3.x

I have a list like

```
ip = ['*', '*', '*', '**', '***', '****', '**', '*', '**', '*']
```

and i need output as somthing like:

```
op = ['1', '2', '3', '3.1', '3.1.1', '3.1.1.1', '3.2', '4', '4.1', '5']
```

It's like a versioning logic. For every single star base value increase by 1, and every multi star it will be x.1,x.1.1,x.1.1.1..like this and for every same star count the decimal place increases(look at 7th element. ** converted to 3.2)...

Need Help in forming the logic for this,,, even i am trying to do it, will post my solution if able to do so..

Thanks in Adv.

Comment: Sorry, but SO is not a free coding service.

Comment: Sounds like a fun exercise, would be a shame to spoil it...

Comment: Agree, it a fun exercise and i am trying to solve it as well, but asking for help is not a crime. Is it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a stack of counters:

```
op = []
i = []
for l in ip:
    while len(i) < len(l):
        i.append(0)
    while len(l) < len(i):
        i.pop()
    i[-1] += 1
    op.append('.'.join(map(str, i)))
```

`op` becomes:

```
['1', '2', '3', '3.1', '3.1.1', '3.1.1.1', '3.2', '4', '4.1', '5']
```

Comment: It works, Thanks, I am trying to use a dictionary to solve it, will post my solution , Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 1):

Does this work for you?
I've made it on the assumption that we always start with one asterisk '*' and then the snippet knows what to do. Basically I have a counter for the number of asterisks and by checking whether the next element is shorter or longer you can null the smaller sections.

```
ll=['*', '*', '*', '**', '***', '****', '**', '*', '**', '*']
sec=[0]*len(max(ll))
sec[0]=1
new=[]
new.append('1')
for (i,s) in zip(range(0,len(ll)-1),ll):
    ls=len(s)
    ls1=len(ll[i+1])
    sec[ls1-1]=sec[ls1-1]+1
    if ls1<ls:
           sec[(ls1):]=[0]*len(sec[ls1:])

    new.append(''.join(str(ss)+'.' for ss in sec if ss!=0)[:-1])
```

Comment: I tried the same as your answer, i missed  the ss!=0 and  [:-1]  in the append part(so my trial was not working)... thanks for your answer :) , and yes, it always starts with a single *. I believe  blhsing 's answer is a compact one and easy to follow, so i have accepted the solution.